Meshes intersection
Good morning everyone!
I have a fundamental problem with combining two meshes to create a single one. Despite all the guides i've consulted on boolean operators and how to join vertices, i don't get the result i want so i'm definitely doing something wrong.
This is a sphere that i would like to join to another mesh, as you can see from the image. I would like to keep the sphere inside the mesh, eliminate the highlighted external portion, and then join the vertices to have a single connectivity matrix without overlapping faces/nodes.
I kindly ask you for help. Thank you!!


If you're trying to sculpt these two then you could probably just join them in Object Mode with Ctrl+J and then run the remesh operator to unify the geo. Have you tried BoolTool yet? It just makes the normal Bool modifier workflow in Blender a little bit easier, but it's built in and ezpz.

Yes i tried to join them in a single object and remesh but then some holes form where the sphere intersect while i would like to keep the shape intact while having the sphere inside.

Hmm, Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Sure, link

I was able to Boolean the two objects together pretty easy. Make sure you enable BoolTool in the addons menu, that makes that alot easier.

Also the Ctrl+J -> Join, followed by Sculpt Mode -> Remesh method seems to work fine.

Result:


Yes it does perform the remeshing but the sphere inside disappear. How can i keep it?

Then you just do ctrl+J to join the objects. No remeshing.

Let me explain better what the problem is.
I'd like to merge the mesh and the sphere into a single object by deleting the portions of the sphere that are outside and then connect the vertices. This can be done with an intersection, but the result is overlapping faces, and i don't know how to get rid of them to connect the vertices. Thanks for your patience.

Do two boolean operations. One intersection to get the part of the sphere inside the bigger mesh, then do a difference mod on the bigger object with the sphere object to "clear space" for the intersecting object to sit.

Thanks for the answer. The intersection works pretty well in excluding the outer parts of the sphere, but then the difference does not delete the intersecting faces; they are just fragmented, probably because the mesh doesn't have a thickness. I honestly don't know how to handle this.

Yeah I think your problem is you're using the same object being booled to then bool other objects. Duplicate each object so that you have two pairs; Big one intersecting small one & small one subtracting big one. Don't use the same big one in both operations.
